# SecondActivity not working when Shared Preferences are used

Tags: android, android-studio

I was doing activity where I had to save some values in the Shared Preferences but this activity would not open now. In this problem it's showing zero errors in my code so I am not able to understand where and what to be modified

JavaCode:

```
public class CreateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences list= getSharedPreferences("LIST_PREF",MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = list.edit();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);

        RadioGroup dur = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        dur.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                String duration = "None";
                switch (checkedId){
                    case R.id.radioButtonDay:
                        duration = "Day";
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioButtonMonth:
                        duration = "Month";
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioButtonYear:
                        duration = "Year";
                }
                editor.putString("Duration",duration);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
    }
    public void createList(View v) {
        EditText listName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextListName);
        EditText budget = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBudgetLimit);
        String nameList = listName.getText().toString();
        int budgetLimit = Integer.valueOf(budget.getText().toString());

        if(nameList.length() == 0)
            listName.setError("List Name is required!!");
        if(budgetLimit == 0)
            budget.setError("Budget Limit is not set");

        editor.putString("ListName",nameList);
        editor.putInt("BudgetLimit",budgetLimit);
        editor.commit();

    }
}
```

I have found this on debugging but i have no clue what to make out of this. I could just make out that there is some error in my Shared Prefs but I don't understand what is it and how to solve or debug.
LOGCAT:

```
2020-10-08 20:13:00.399 18073-18073/com.example.yourbudget E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.yourbudget, PID: 18073
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yourbudget/com.example.yourbudget.CreateActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2876)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:184)
    at com.example.yourbudget.CreateActivity.<init>(CreateActivity.java:17)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to initialize the `SharedPreferences` instance in the `onCreate()` method, since the context is not attached to your activity yet (until it reaches `onCreate()`)

Answer (score 1):

the erorr say :

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'android.content.SharedPreferences
> android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)'
> ****on a null object reference`****

so ask your self which is the null object reference?
your getSharedPreferences get called by your context this means your context (Activity) is  a null object reference
(doesn't be created yet )
and
that is yes because on create doesn`t call first before you call this method

Comment: I initialized the object in the onCreate() and it resolved the error

Comment: fine, happy coding